# NameError: name '__file__' is not defined , os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

Tags: python, error-handling, filepath, file-handling

I'm trying to use os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**)) for tracking my file txt but i don't why its not working with me:

```
  import os

  print(os.getcwd()) # Get Working directory

  print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
  file = open("Youness.txt")
```

---

```
  NameError: name '__file__' is not defined.
```

Comment: You ran this code directly in the terminal, (or with F9 in the IDE spyder for example). Copy this code a brand new file name "whatever.py" and then in your terminal write : python whatever.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good chance that __ file __ is not defined because you execute your code in an interactive shell.

Write it in a file and execute it with python and the const __ file __ will be defined.

Hope it helps.